# Planetary Scan Job does not show the target

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

Here is the situation: I accepted a planetary scan job and I went to the system. I've scanned the system beacon and use your Advanced Discovery Scanner but the message telling me which of the planets is the target does not arrive.

I've follow these [instructions](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/threads/planetary-scan-job.357324/), but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I just exit the game to the main menu and entered again. Just after the game loaded, the message arrived and I was able to finish the mission (?).

Comment: If you have the details of the job - report it as a bug - you shouldn't need to exit to main menu for things to appear.

Answer (score 1):

this can happen with any kind of mission that involves finding the mission location, here is an example scenario:

```
1. you accepted a planetary scan job mission
2. you either scanned the target system with a scanner or scanned the nav beacon
3. you receiver the message that the mission contact received the system data(or something like that)
4. but you don't see the new location
```

i had that happen to me a number of times, not with only planetary scan missions

now there are a couple of ways to fix it:

1. as you said yourself, log out, log back in
2. go super cruise
3. knowing elite there is some weird ass dark voodoo magic 3rd way to fix it, but i didn't find it yet

im honestly too lazy to re-log in for a mission, so when i can't find the target location after scanning the initial target, im going to fly away, but as soon as im back to super cruise i get the new target

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/295888)

Comment: oh right, ill make an edit

Comment: annnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnd, done